# How to travel to Bangkok, Thailand from Siem Reap, Cambodia?

Tags: thailand, cambodia

I just wanted to inquire the easiest way to get to Bangkok, Thailand from Siem Reap, Cambodia.

Can I use the same VISA taken for Cambodia to travel to Thailand ? If not how to get to Thailand by road and by air?

Natioanlity - Indian Citizen

Comment: What do you mean with *easiest*? Time, paperwork, distance? Please [edit] your question. And make sure you do not ask two questions in one.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go is flying, takes less than two hours via direct flights between Siem Reap and Bangkok (several airlines offer flights).  The cheapest way is by bus, but that involves two buses, with a change at the border and basically a full day out of your schedule.

No, your visa for Cambodia does not provide access to Thailand.  Whether you need a visa or qualify under the visa exemption rule for Thailand is dependent on your nationality which you neglected to mention.